# Undefined variable in view when pulling specific data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

It says `undefined variable` when I try to pull variable through compact

this is my controller

```
public function show()
{
    $list = List::find(1)->task();
    return view('configuration.configuration', compact($list));
}
```

this is my view

```
@foreach($list as $value)

           <span> {{ $value->tasks }}</span>

@endforeach
```

Comment: I think you had better check what `compact()` does http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SUGGESTIONS/CORRECTIONS**

In `$list = List::find(1)->task();` If you are trying to retrieve all `task` from list, then I this you are doing it wrong instead you should do something like this:

```
$list = List::find(1)->task;
```

Again in `return view('configuration.configuration', compact($list));`, if you want to convert to array then `compact()` won't do that.

this `return view('configuration.configuration', ['list'=>$list->toArray()]);` will do that

An to retrieve or print in `view(blade)`, try something like this

```
@foreach($list as $value=>$val)
   <span> {{{ $val['task'] }}}</span> //"task" is just an assumption, replace it with your own ColumnName
@endforeach
```

**if you don't want convert the `$list` in array**

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function show()
{
    $list = List::find(1)->task;
    return view('configuration.configuration',['list'=> $list]);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@foreach($list as $value)
   <span> {{ $value->tasks }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your return view to :

```
return view('configuration.configuration',['list'=>$list]);
```

Comment: but I don't need to pull only one table I'm using two tables that are connected with foreign key(there are more than one list) so I can't pull only one table

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `compact()` try `with($list)`